# Getting weird phantom horizontal scrollbar... what?

Tags: jquery, css

So I had to change my container to something other than position: fixed; and now I get a weird horizontal scrollbar... even if I try to hide the X overflow. What up with that?
http://www.graysonearle.com/Lumarca is the site

Comment: I don't see that in FF3.6 on a 1280x1024 display.

Comment: the best way to locate a problem is to create a minimalistic example which reproduces it

Comment: chrome on OS X also fine. No scrollbar here

Comment: OOPS ok uploaded the version that's giving me trouble! sorry.

Comment: I don't see a horizontal scroll bar (FF 10, multiple window sizes tried), but I do see an unnecessary vertical scroll bar.  Was that what you meant?  Got rid of it by setting the position value of your #video div to relative (from absolute).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the width from the following:

```
#nav {
   position: absolute;
    width: 1024px; // remove this line
    top: 36px;
    display: inline;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

1024px is the width of your document but because the nav is positioned inline next to the logo, it is pushing the document out to the right and causing a scroll bar to appear.

You seem to have some other layout problems in Chrome. the nav isn't even visible until I load the developer tools.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I had to do that to a few of the divs and then header had to be set manually for it to show correctly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Found in your source : style.css on line 1

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

It makes no sense to put overflow on html element, you should put it on the body element.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue for IE. You need to add `position:relative` on your body class where you have defined `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, defining an `overflow` on the `html` element is causing the browser to ignore the one on the `body`.  Remove the `overflow-y` from the `html` element and it works as expected.

If it is needed, put it on the `body` instead.